# R programming- Minimize a function(RMSE) with constrained variables

Tags: r, optimization, statistics, solver, lpsolve

I want to minimize a function (rmse) in R just like solver does in excel. Using the constrained vaiables (i) and conditioning it for

```
**i >= 0 && i<=2**

ac = c(85,95,79,88,90,99,111,99,100,110)
ff = c(100,110,105,95,115,105,110,120,105,110)
ff1 = ff[2:5] ;ac1 = ac[2:5]
i=1.1 #Assume-Constraint variable
revff = ff1*i
dev1 = abs(ac1-revff)
rmse_function = function(ac1,ff1,i) sqrt(sum(abs(ac1-ff1*i)^2))
```

I want to minimize the function rmse by changing the variable i.

Comment: `rmse` isn't a function.

Comment: Hello, I've updated the function

Answer (score 0):

Write your function so its the *first* argument you want to minimise over, use `optimise`:

```
> rmse_function = function(i,ac1,ff1)sqrt(sum(abs(ac1-ff1*i)^2))
> optimise(rmse_function,c(0,2),ac1=ac1, ff1=ff1)
$minimum
[1] 0.8254548

$objective
[1] 13.87804
```

Hence the minimum is at `i=0.825` and the function has a value of `13.87` there.

Comment: Thank you! 
That worked like a charm, now I've even wrote it for Weighted Average and MAE too.